# ASP.NET MVC 4 Map Route to a specific controller does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

i have a problem with my route map for a specific controller. I looked for some other answers for this, but i they didn't helped me a lot.

Following rote map do i have:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Default",
              url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new { culture = LanguageHelper.GetDefaultCultureToken(), controller = "Forum", action = "Overview", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
              namespaces: new string[] { "MyForum.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "AccRoute",
          url: "Account/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Overview", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
          namespaces: new string[] { "MyForum.Controllers" }
        );
```

My problem is, that the second route map don't work. 
I can't find the route with the following link: "~/account/confirm/iHUeMMOL9XA2vqqV6XGJ-w2"

Best regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That URL is matching the first route, to avoid that you need to use constraints, for example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { culture = LanguageHelper.GetDefaultCultureToken(), controller = "Forum", action = "Overview", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
   constraints: new { culture = @"[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}" },
   namespaces: new string[] { "MyForum.Controllers" });
```

Not sure my Regex works for you, but you get the idea. That way the segment `account` will not match.

Comment: The first map route is not my problem. I have links which routes directly to the account controller, like my example link, so i need a second map route.

Comment: Ok thank you alot! That was my problem. The second map route was covert by the first one.